# Selecting multiple attributes with variables using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I'm working on a program for my work and I'm trying to select multiple power line segments from the same shapefile. I'm having trouble with my SQL syntax to pass both variables on to the selection process in the program. I've tried both the 'or' and 'in' queries. The line of code worked with just one variable, but it still only passes one variable after I added the second one.  Any suggestions?

```
import arcpy

line_val1 = raw_input('Enter Line Number: ')
line_val2 = raw_input('Enter Line Number: ')

expression = str(""" "LINE_NUM_1" = '""" + line_val1 + "'" or """ "LINE_NUM_1" = '""" + line_val2 + "'")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(line_out, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

Comment: IMHO string math is an ugly way to format strings, prone to failure.  Instead, use the `string.format()` function: `expression = "\"LINE_NUM_1\" = '{:s}' or \"LINE_NUM_1\" = '{:s}'".format(line_val1,line_val2)`. Also valid: `expression = "\"LINE_NUM_1\" in ('{:s}','{:s}')".format(line_val1,line_val2)`.  If in doubt, print the resulting string before using it, and place it in the table selection tool to validate. (Note that this assumes  LINE_NUM_1 is a `text` field -- remove the single quotes if integer, and change the `:s` to `:d`.)

Comment: The field is a text field so your line of code worked great. Thank you for the help and information!

Answer (score 3):

Your `or` is outside your string.

```
expression = """ "LINE_NUM_1" = '""" + line_val1 + "' or "\"LINE_NUM_1\" = '" + line_val2 + "'"
```

I like using `IN` and `format`, myself.

```
""""LINE_NUM_1" IN ('{}', '{}')""".format (line_val1, line_val2)
```

Comment: The double quotes around the field name are unnecessary. Once they are dropped you can replace the triple double quotes with single double quotes for an easier to read expression.

Answer (score 0):

This simple one use AND/OR I can't format the script using phone

```
query1 = " LINE_NUM_1= '" + line1_val + "'"
query2 = "LINE_NUM_2 = '" + line2_val+ "'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer,"NEW_SELECTION", "{0} AND {1} ".format(query1,query2,))
```

Comment: You can code-format text on a phone by using four-spaces on each line or a pair of triple-backquotes (above and below). Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect, because the problem was an OR statement, and your solution is an AND (which won't ever return any rows).

Comment: Yes you are right he can replace AND by OR in the last line